# Change timezone for github pages

Tags: github, github-pages, github-actions

I have used the github page for reporting. The timezone of the page is not correct.

I tried to change the timezone in the  **_config.yml** file by adding

```
timezone: "Europe/Paris"
```

it is still using a different timezone.

Appreciate your help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

found the solution. i changed the timezone of the server using

```
export TZ="Europe/Paris"
```